# Weatherproofing a cheap ultrasonic sensor

Tags: sensor, ultrasound

Is there a way to weatherproof a [cheap ($15-25) ultrasonic sensor](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Ultra_Sonic_range_measurement_module) for moderate outdoor use? I know Maxbotix sells weatherproof sensors, but these run for $100 each, which is too steep for my project. I just need a sensor to resist light rain. Is there any simple modification I can do, like cover the sensor in saran-wrap, to protect it from small amounts of moisture? i.e. What firm materials are transparent to ultrasound?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the module you linked to can be found at ebay for ~$2 ([check this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Arduino-Ultrasonic-Module-HC-SR04-Distance-Sensor-Measuring-Transducer-hg-/281513123961?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item418b7d6079)) and [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-1pc-18mm-40khz-Waterproof-Ultrasonic-Sensor-Receiver-Transmitter-R-T-in-1-/290936672729?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43bd2d51d9) you can find only the waterproof sensors (Rx and TX) for about ~$5, so maybe you can get those two (the cheap module and the waterproof sensors) and swap the non-waterproof with the waterproof if their specs matches.

Or get a waterproof one that is ready with the module for about ~$14 [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Waterproof-Non-contact-Distance-Ranging-Ultrasonic-Sensor-Module-Motion-Detector-/360857671987?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5404cb1933)

or this one which is mostly used for car parking assist kits for ~$16 [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Ultrasonic-Module-Distance-Measuring-Transducer-Sensor-Perfect-Waterproof-/141478062843?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20f0bfeafb)

you still need to protect the circuit board but that should be easy.

Comment: The first link isn't the same sensor I linked to. It's actually an older junkier 4-pin version that I definitely don't want, which is probably why it's so cheap. But yes, I saw those other sensors on Ebay, and dismissed them because they seem too good to be true. They're from some no-name Chinese company, they provide no documentation and they mis-label it as "DYP-ME007", which you can see is definitely wrong if you Google "DYP-ME007". I'm not really sure what those on-board waterproof sensors are. How is a bare-circuit board waterproof?

Comment: It is EXACTLY the same, seeed studio was one of those unknown Chinese companies and they will fabricate PCBs for people and give them offers (like free PBC) if they open source their hardware design so seeed can resell it under their name. Anyways, if you think because if it more expensive then it is better that is up to you. But i am using the cheap one and it works great. Also you can find the 4 pin which allows you to control the pings, or get a 3 pin version that pings continuously.

Comment: And for the other ones I have already mentioned that you need to protect the circuit, which is very easy to do, however it is the sensor that you cannot easily shield it yourself and you need to get one that is manufactured with materials that won't block or reflect the ultrasound signals.

Comment: Googling DYP-ME007 shows same modules which is expected since they are all based on the same design, so I don't really see your point.

Answer (score 2):

A firm material by definition can't be transparent to ultrasound, you can try putting it in a pipe and sloping it downwards to avoid the rain. Or maybe see if putting some plastic wrap over the end of the pipe will allow some of it to get through, I'm skeptical though.